# How can I superimpose an image on the frame of the camera (in real time)?

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an object recognition program with opencv and android, the program basically makes the moment the real time camera recognizes the object displays an image with information of the object in augmented reality form on the frame of the camera.

The problem is that it shows an error in the addition of the images how can I successfully do the addition?

The images are not of the same size.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat aInputFrame) {
// Crear una imagen en escala de grises
Imgproc.cvtColor(aInputFrame, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

Mat imagen = Highgui.imread(ruta, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
Rect roi = new Rect(150, 200, 40, 60);
MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

// Utilice el clasificador para detectar rostros
if (cascadeClassifier != null) {
    cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayscaleImage, faces, 1.1, 2, 2,
            new Size(absoluteFaceSize, absoluteFaceSize), new Size());
}

Mat copia = aInputFrame.clone();
Mat imgroi = imagen.submat(roi);
Mat salidaroi = copia.submat(roi);

Core.addWeighted(imgroi, 0.5, imagen, 0.2, 1,  salidaroi);

return salidaroi;
```

}

Error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x
>   + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const Rect&),
>   file
>   /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp,
>   line 323

Comment: can you post sample images and your desired result?

Comment: Well, you are trying to add a big image with a small image, how can the function know which part of the big image will be added to the small image?  They have to be the same size, I think it is better to do this part manually? you can try to do copy of the small region in the original image, blend it as it is in your code and then copy this region to the big image.... not sure if in java you can reference a roi as in c++, if you can then that way you save copying the small region